# Forward declare a boost::multi_index_container object

Tags: c++, boost, forward-declaration, boost-multi-index

I have been wondering how to forward declare a `boost::multi_index_container` for awhile.

There are `multi_index_container_fwd.hpp`, `ordered_index_fwd.hpp` and so on in the `multi_index` directories.

They are supposed to be hidden the implementation from the part of the program that does not need to know the details of the object, right?

However, I can't figure out a way to declare a `multi_index_container` with those *_fwd.hpp files alone.

I have been always included the full implementation file, `multi_index_container.hpp` index.

Answer (score 2):

In principle you should be able to forward declare, for instance, functions that depend on a `multi_index_container` type by using the appropriate `*_fwd.hpp` headers. But not every situation can be handled this way:

```
class A{
  ...
private:
  multi_index_container<...>* p; // can use *_fwd.hpp headers
};

class B{
  ...
private:
  multi_index_container<...> m; // needs full headers!!
};
```

There's nothing special with Boost.MultiIndex here: whenever you declare a variable of type `T` whose size needs to be known at compile time, you must have the full definition of `T` in place.